# How to create this custom shape in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-canvas, drawable, figma

How to create this custom shape in android ?
My requirement is, i want to create a CardView with above shape. Inside this cardview, there will be other textviews and imageviews present. Under the top curve of the card, i need to place a small icon.
Can this shape be created in UI design tools like figma ?
If it is possible in Figma, then we can take the XML generated in figma and use it in android code.
[image]

Comment: Using [Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) is one way.

Comment: @Darkman Can i create this as a drawable and set it as background for CardView ?

Comment: why not use a image?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy Yes, of course. Draw it on a custom `Canvas` then use the `Bitmap` for the background. Or like the above commenter said, you can just use an image.

Comment: @Darkman Can you please elaborate your answer ? I'm not able to understand how i can use an image ? My requirement is, i want to create a CardView with above shape. Inside this cardview, there will be other textviews and imageviews present. Just below the top curve of the card, a small icon will be there.

Comment: @Anna Can you please elaborate your answer ? I'm not able to understand how i can use an image ? My requirement is, i want to create a CardView with above shape. Inside this cardview, there will be other textviews and imageviews present. Under the top curve of the card, i need to place a small icon.

Answer (score 0):

create xml file in drawable folder with Root Element "layer-list" and copy this code inside of "layer-list" tag :) ,
add the code to the cardview background

Unfortunately, I could not add the code in the comment
Please see the photo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W74pM.png)